# Specify url for github in github's maven site plugin

Tags: maven, github

I'm using the github maven site plugin from here: https://github.com/github/maven-plugins

I'd like to configure the url for github, since I'm working on a github enterprise installation instead of the regular github server.

I can figure out how to set the id of the server, it's clearly documented in the [README.md](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/blob/master/README.md#pomxml):

```
<properties>
  <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
</properties>
```

However, I can't figure out how to configure the URL for the server.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was making things more difficult than they needed to be.  The com.github.github.site-maven-plugin supports a `<host>` parameter inside `<configuration>` that was all I needed to use.